# Input and output layer activation functions of neurons in Orange

Tags: neural-network, orange, activation-function

What are the activation functions of the neurons in the input and output layer of a neural network model from the Orange machine learning application?

Answer (score 0):

The activation functions are used in hidden layers and output layer. The output layer will usually have sigmoid or softmax activation while hidden layers usually use ReLU. ReLU is available in Orange at least (there is a dropdown which you can explore but ReLU works best mostly, read [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/relu-rules-lets-understand-why-its-popularity-remains-unshaken-ccfe952fc5b1)). Also, check this link for looking at [neural networks](https://orange3.readthedocs.io/projects/orange-visual-programming/en/latest/widgets/model/neuralnetwork.html) in Orange.